# Ajax Form Step Tracking - Google Analytics

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager, ajaxform

We have an ajax form with multiple steps. We would like to track each step as a pageview (seeing as a new url is not generated with ajax). Would creating a virtual pageview per step be a good option?

Side note: We make use of Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Yes definitely you can (and I'd be even so bold to say "should") deploy virtual page views for AJAX pages. As this question is not about coding, it should be closed.

Comment: Thanks Nyuen! This is definitely the way we will go then.